# Plotting the 2-d diffusion equation over time

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot, numerical-methods

So basically, I've created a plot in python which models two interacting populations on an island and shows the uses the diffusion equation to model the movement and change in the population in one dimension, and I'm trying to modify it so I have a two dimensional plot instead so it takes into account both the x and y position of the species on the island.

Apologies that the code is quite long, most of it is just defining parameters though- I'm not too sure how I create a two dimensional plot which has the density of the population in each position, this is my attempt below but the plot isn't correct at all. I think my numerical solution should be correct, I'm assuming it's it's my initial/boundary conditions and how I've set up my array for the probability distribution which is incorrect but I'm not sure how to change it. For example, one of the problems I have is that it has the Y position on the x axis - how can I fix this?

```
r1=0.1 # growth rate B
r2=0.3 # growth rate M
KB = 20 # carrying capacity B
KM = 6000 # carrying capacity M
x=np.arange(0,70) # distance from the coast (100m)
y=np.arange(0,90) # distance from the coast
dx=1 # change in x position
dy=1 # change in y position
dt=1 # time step
m=71 # number of x steps
o=91 # number of y steps
n=21 # time
alpha =  0.00002 # predation rate
beta = 0 # growth rate from predation (assumed to be zero)

B=np.zeros(shape=(m,o,n)) # species B 
M=np.zeros(shape=(m,o,n)) # species M
D=0.35 # diffusivity of B
D2=0.05 # diffusivity of M
Alpha=(D*dt)/(dx*dx)
Beta=(D*dt)/(dy*dy) 
Alpha2=(D2*dt)/(dx*dx)
Beta2 = (D2*dt)/(dy*dy)

M[0,:,0]=0 #initial conditions
M[m-1,:,0]=0
M[:,0,0]=0
M[:,m-1,0]=0
B[1:26,:,0]=0.96
B[26:44,:,0]=4.6
B[44:m-1,:,0]=0.96
B[:,1:26,0]=0.96
B[:,26:44,0]=4.6
B[:,44:m-1,0]=0.96
M[1:26,:,0]=2500
M[26:44,:,0]=1000
M[44:m-1,:,0]=2500
M[:,1:26,0]=2500
M[:,26:44,0]=1000
M[:,44:m-1,0]=2500
for k in range(0,n-1): # loop for time
    B[0,:,k+1]=B[1,:,k+1] # boundary conditions
    B[m-1,:,k+1]=B[m-2,:,k+1]
    M[0,:,k+1]=0
    M[m-1,:,k+1]=0
    B[:,0,k+1]=B[:,1,k+1]
    B[:,m-1,k+1]=B[:,m-2,k+1]
    M[:,0,k+1]=0
    M[:,m-1,k+1]=0
    for i in range(1,m-1): # loop for x
        for j in range(1,o-1): # loop for y
            Bdxx=(-2*Alpha)*B[i,j,k]+Alpha*B[i+1,j,k]+Alpha*B[i-1,j,k]
            Bdyy=(-2*Beta)*B[i,j,k]+Beta*B[i,j+1,k]+Beta*B[i,j-1,k]
            B[i,j,k+1]=B[i,j,k]+Bdxx+Bdyy+r1*B[i,j,k]*(1-B[i,j,k]/KB)-alpha*M[i,j,k]*B[i,j,k] # numerical solution for B 
            Mdxx=(-2*Alpha2)*M[i,j,k]+Alpha2*M[i+1,j,k]+Alpha2*M[i-1,j,k]
            Mdyy=(-2*Beta2)*M[i,j,k]+Beta2*M[i,j+1,k]+Beta2*M[i,j-1,k]
            M[i,j,k+1]=M[i,j,k]+Mdxx+Mdyy+r2*M[i,j,k]*(1-M[i,j,k]/KM)+beta*M[i,j,k]*B[i,j,k] # numerical solution for M


plt.pcolormesh(B[:,:,n-1]) 
plt.colorbar()
plt.xlabel('X Position')
plt.ylabel('Y Position')
```

Any help is really appreciated, thanks!

edit: I've realised part of my problem is that the initial conditions for the y coordinates are wrong